# C# ComboBox - Call function in DataContext via SelectionChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I have a ComboBox that looks like this:

```
<ComboBox Text="Choose program" Margin="5" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding ProgramsToChooseFrom}"
    SelectedValue="{Binding CurrentProgId, Mode=TwoWay}"
    SelectedValuePath="Id"
    DisplayMemberPath="ProgName" SelectionChanged="Function_SelectionChanged">
</ComboBox>
```

The window is a `CourseEditorWindow` with a `CourseViewModel` DataContext.

```
_courseViewModel = new CourseViewModel(_model);
_editorView = new CourseEditorWindow();
_editorView.DataContext = _courseViewModel;
_editorView.Show();
```

I'm trying to run a function when the selection is changed (to update another combobox's values). For this I'm using `SelectionChanged="Function_SelectionChanged"` but apparently this looks for the function in the window's code, since right now `Function_SelectionChanged` is implemented in the DataContext of the window, and I'm getting the error :

> 'CourseEditorWindow' does not contain a definition for
>   'Function_SelectionChanged' and no extension method
>   'Function_SelectionChanged' accepting a first argument of type
>   'CourseEditorWindow' could be found (are you missing a using directive
>   or an assembly reference?)

How can I call a function via XAML from my combobox, that is defined in the window's DataContext? Basically I'm trying to call `_courseViewModel.Function_SelectionChanged` whenever the selection is changed.

Comment: you would need to do something in the setter of the `CurrentProgId` of your ViewModel and remove `SelectionChanged` event, as setter will be called whenever selection is changed in combobox

Comment: Try using `SelectedItem` for your `ComboBox`. And then handle the change through your `VM`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually need to call the method in the setter of `CurrentProgId` in your `CourseViewModel` as it will be called whenever the selection of combo-box get's changed which would be something like:

```
private int _currentProgId;
public int CurrentProgId
{
  get { return _currentProgId; }
  set
  {
    _currentProgId= value;
    CallSomeMethod();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use another strategy, rather than looking for the event you should check for any modification in your view-model (or DataContext) object in the  CurrentProgId property.